# The file is still being rewritten even when "No" or an invalid option is entered

Tags: c

The code is supposed to overwrite or clear the file when Yes is entered, but it still does so when No or anything else is entered.

```c
void createCanteenFoodFile()
{

    FILE* fp;
    int i,t=0;
    char ans;
    struct food foodie={0,"","",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};

    if ((fp = fopen("food", "wb"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Are you sure you want to create a new file?\nThis will overwrite any previous data\n\n");
        printf("Type Yes or No\n");
        scanf("%c",&ans);
        if(ans=='Y' or ans=='y')
        {
            for (i=0;i<=100;i++)
            {
                fwrite(&foodie,sizeof(struct food),1,fp);//food file created
            }
            printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("\t\t        FILE CREATED\t\t\n");
            printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        else if(ans=='N' or ans=='n')
        {
            printf("Option denied\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t\t   ERROR - Invalid option\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `fopen("food", "wb")` works, the content of the file is already gone. You should ask before you open the file.

Comment: `if(ans=='Y' or ans=='y')`???  `or` is not a proper C operator.

Comment: [The written versions of the logical operators](//stackoverflow.com/q/2376448)

Comment: `fwrite` does not create a file; `fopen` does.  The misplaced comments demonstrate the misunderstandintg.  Move `// food file created` from the `fwrite` to the `fopen`.

Comment: @Yunnosch (also @Andrew Henle): please read C11 [§7.9 Alternative spellings `<iso646.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.9).  Granted, it isn't often used, but it certainly can be used.

Comment: Note the caveats about [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for notifying me of that interesting header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file with the "wb" flags will remove all previous content of the file, regardless of if you ever write to it. To solve your issue you would have to move your call to fopen till after you got confirmation that the file should be deleted.